# Div 0 in inline if else multiple assignment

Tags: python

```
Hz = 0
assert Hz >= 0, "Frequency cannot have negative number"

state, fA, fB = States.RESTING, INF, INF \
    if Hz == 0 else States.ACTIVE, 1 / Hz, 1 / Hz
```

Causes below error

```
    if Hz == 0 else States.ACTIVE, 1 / Hz, 1 / Hz
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

The expected behavior when received `0` for `Hz`, is to assign `States.RESTING, INF, INF` respectively to `state, fA, fB`.
Why is the interpreter evaluating the else part?

Comment: add parenthesis : (States.RESTING, INF, INF)    if Hz == 0 else (States.ACTIVE, 1 / Hz, 1 / Hz)

Comment: @Erwan Your solution solved the problem. But why doesn't it work without the parenthesis?

Comment: there is precedence between operator without parenthesis python understand this : 
 States.RESTING, INF, (INF if Hz == 0 else States.ACTIVE), 1 / Hz, 1 / Hz)

Comment: the link in the python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `if` is acting only on the last assignment. To give the correct priority, add parentheses:

```
state, fA, fB = (States.RESTING, INF, INF) \
    if Hz == 0 else (States.ACTIVE, 1 / Hz, 1 / Hz)
```

Comment: So to make it clear, without the parentheses, you would have to write if else per each assignment?

Comment: Yes. `state, fA, fB = States.RESTING if Hz == 0 else States.Active, INF if Hz == 0 else  1 / Hz, INF if Hz == 0 else  1 / Hz`

Comment: But I would say that the solution with the parentheses is much easier to parse.